# iPhone 6 Plus and horizontal scrolling of questions threads

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, ios-app

Would be nice to have the same UI experience on the iPhone 6 Plus as users of the 6 and 5s with respect to the horizontal scrolling of threads.

When we spoke at the [Brooklyn iOS Dev meet-up](http://www.meetup.com/The-Brooklyn-iPhone-and-iPad-Developer-Meetup/events/205984482/) a couple of weeks ago at Stack Exchange, you said you would fix this issue. Please let me know when you get around to it. Thanks.

See below the difference: (iPhone 5S to the left, iPhone 6 plus to the right)

> [image: feed via 5s]               [image: feed via 6 plus]

Comment: Do you mean using the iOS app, or just the mobile theme?

Comment: Yes the iOS App on the 6 Plus. The user experience is not the same as that for iPhone 6 or 5 users. It's more like the iPad because of the wider screen dimensions. I'd much rather have the horizontal scrolling feature that appears in the feed on the latter phones

Comment: OK, so that's a feature request. Retagging...

Comment: Well not so fast. I don't think that behavior was intended for the iPhone 6 Plus, I think this is a bug. To make my point I'll attempt to enclose two screenshots one from the iPhone 5s and the other from the 6 plus so u can see the difference. IMHO, the experience should be the same on either iPhone platform. It's not an iPad

Comment: Fair enough, let's leave this for the dev team to decide then.

Answer (score 2):

The was definitely *intended* as a feature and not a bug.  We've been trying it out because landscape is an important use case for the 6+ and the phone feed is ridiculously sparse on ridiculously wide screens.

The next build will have the phone-style feed.